# Mysql subquery IN clause Find by JSON Value

Tags: mysql, json, subquery

I have two tables.  One is product_details and another one is size.
 Each product have multiple sizes.
 I have to get set of size for each products.(like 100, 125, 150).  
But i already saved the size record as JSON value (like ["1","2","8"]) in product_details table.
 
When i try to get the record using IN clause & Subquery, i can't able to get the records. 
Check this link: [click here sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a6e8/2)

```
SELECT po_det.po_det_size as json_str, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(po_det.po_det_size, '[',''),']',''),'"','')) str,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(size.size_name)
 FROM tbl_product_size size
 WHERE size.size_id IN (str)
) AS sizes
FROM tbl_purchase_order_details po_det
```

Please help me to get the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `in` for this.  You can use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(size.size_id, str) > 0
```

I don't think you can use a column alias in the subquery, so that might be another problem:

```
where find_in_set(size.size_id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(po_det.po_det_size, '[',''),']',''),'"',''))) > 0
```